Benefits of chanting shiva Sahasranama
What are the benefits of shiva Sahasranama ? Can it remove or burn bad karmas and sins live the shiva mahimna stotra. Does the scripture mention anything about removing sins from one’s life if shiva Sahasranama is chanted ? Thank you.

Lord Shiva himself explained the benefits of chanting shiva sahasranama in Siva purana
[From shiva purana Kotirudra Samhita Chapter 36]


There is no doubt that those who recite and teach this hymn will have no misery at all even in dreams.

When kings are in distress this worship with thousand names shall be repeated hundred times in accordance with the rules laid down and
after due performance of the ancillary services people will have
welfare.

This is destructive of distress. It yields learning and wealth. It is excellent and meritorious and bestows all desires and devotion to
Śiva always.

People undoubtedly derive excellent benefits which they will have in view in reciting this.

Achievement is not far off if a person rising in the morning, performs my worship and recites this in my presence everyday.

There is no doubt in this that he will attain all the worldly pleasures and desires and in the end Sāyujya type of salvation.




Will it reduce my sins ?

@Sillyasker ofcourse
